# PLSQL: ORA-00933 why is INTO not working?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working on a PLSQL Script, but there is an error - I don't know what's wrong ;(

Im so sorry for this silly question, but I really don't know the solution.
Can somebody help me?

This is my Code:

```
DECLARE
  tagnow  webtags_20161221.editionid%TYPE;
BEGIN
  select editionid from webtags w, edition e
  into tagnow *the word into is red underlined*
  where editionid in (
  select editionid from (
  select editionid, tag, count(*) from webtags
  group by editionid, tag
  having count(*) > 1))
  and editionid = editionid
  order by createdat desc;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
     tagnow);
END;
```

Why isn't it working? the error is:

```
ORA-06550: Line 5, Column 3:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933
ORA-06550: Line 4, Column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Please help me, I'm beginner.

Comment: "SELECT -- INTO -- FROM -- etc.." is the correct order

Comment: @Thomas thank you so much! I was wrong.

Comment: [Because that isn't the correct syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#CJADDIHJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INTO` goes just after the `SELECT` part, before the `FROM`.

```
select e.editionid
into tagnow
from webtags w, edition e
```

Also, try to learn standard ANSI JOIN, instead of using this old Oracle way, and pay attention in using aliases in joiur join conditions.
You query would become:

```
SELECT e.editionid
  INTO tagnow
  FROM webtags w
  INNER JOIN edition e
  ON (w.editionid = e.editionid)
 WHERE e.editionid IN (... );
```

Another way, where aliases may be not strictly necessary ( but it is a good practice to use them however):

```
SELECT editionid
  INTO tagnow
  FROM webtags w
  INNER JOIN edition e
  USING (editionid)
 WHERE editionid IN (... );
```

Also, you do not need a double nested query; you may use:

```
SELECT editionid
FROM webtags
GROUP BY editionid, tag
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: second one looks wrong too, shouldnt you pay attention in using aliases?

Comment: still one editionid without alias

Comment: so inattentive! Thanks